# Cannot go to show action nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

student_classes_controller.rb

```
class StudentClassesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :set_batch
    def index
        @sections = StudentClass.all
    end
    def show
        @section = StudentClass.find(params[:id])
    end

     private
  def set_batch
    @batch = Batch.find(params[:batch_id])
  end
end
```

in the view of student_classes/index.html.erb

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead bgcolor="#B7B7B7">
      <th>Section</th>
      <th>Number of Students</th>
      <th>Details</th>
    </thead>
    <% @sections.each do |section| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= section.name %></td>
      <td><%= section.students.count %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'View Details', batch_student_classes_path(@batch , section) %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
```

the url of view details is this `http://localhost:3000/batches/1/student_classes.1`
but i want to make it as this `http://localhost:3000/batches/1/student_classes/1`

routes.rb

```
resources :batches do
    resources :student_classes
  end
```

rake routes

```
   batch_student_classes GET    /batches/:batch_id/student_classes(.:format)              student_classes#index
                         POST   /batches/:batch_id/student_classes(.:format)              student_classes#create
 new_batch_student_class GET    /batches/:batch_id/student_classes/new(.:format)          student_classes#new
edit_batch_student_class GET    /batches/:batch_id/student_classes/:id/edit(.:format)     student_classes#edit
     batch_student_class GET    /batches/:batch_id/student_classes/:id(.:format)          student_classes#show
                         PUT    /batches/:batch_id/student_classes/:id(.:format)          student_classes#update
                         DELETE /batches/:batch_id/student_classes/:id(.:format)          student_classes#destroy
```

Comment: show your routes file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path method you want to call is `batch_student_class_path` not **batch_student_class**es**_path**.

Comment: thanks just noticed this ! i hate typos :D thank you

Comment: one more thing please, now when i create another batch , it shows all student classes for all batches , the same with this link_to in here , it shows all students of all student_classes not just the students who belongs to that student_class

Comment: show your models, you need to use the associations instead of just calling `find` and `all` at StudentClass.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares sir, you are a legend! I couldn't for the life of me see that!